# $\| f g\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_\infty$ . Is it true?

Tags: real-analysis

It looks obvious. I try to show it by definition of esssup, but not yet...

Comment: Can you show it for the actual supremum instead of the essential supremum?

Comment: $\sup(|fg|) \leq \sup(|f| sup(|g|)) = \sup(|f|)\sup(|g|)$

Comment: Okay. Now note that the essential supremum of $\lvert h\rvert$ is the actual supremum of $\lvert h\rvert$ over a subset of the domain (the subset depends on $h$). Try to use that.

Comment: Let me think more, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple  proof: almost everywhere,
$$
|f(x) g(x)| = |f(x)|\times |g(x)|  \le \|f\|_\infty \times \|g\|_\infty
\\\implies \|fg\|_\infty\le \|f\|_\infty \times \|g\|_\infty
$$

Comment: indeed. ${{{}}}$